# subclass not inhereting method from superclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

i have never experienced this.

I have a class `Loja`. `Loja` has various subclasses.

```
 public abstract class Loja {

/**
 * Corresponde ao valor da area da loja
 */
private double area;

/**
 * Nome da loja
 */
private String nome;

/**
 * Valor da renda fixa atribuida a todas as lojas
 */
private static double rendaFixa = 200;
/**
 * Área por omissão das lojas
 */
private static final double AREA_POR_OMISSAO = 0;

/**
 * Nome por omissão das lojas
 */
private static final String NOME_POR_OMISSAO = "sem nome";
/**
 * clasificação inferior por omissão dda loja
 */
private static final int CLASSIFICACAO_INFERIOR = 20;

/**
 * Classificação superior por omissão da loja
 */
private static final int CLASSIFICACAO_SUPERIOR = 100;

/**
 * dividendo da àrea para calcular a renda a pagar
 */
private static final int DIVIDENDO_DE_AREA = 100;

/**
 * Classificação da loja
 */
enum Classificacao {
    /**
     * classificação pequena
     */
    pequena(),
    /**
     * classificação média
     */
    media(),
    /**
     * classificação grande
     */
    grande();
}

/**
 * Instância uma instância Loja recebendo como parametro um double area e
 * uma String nome
 *
 * @param area Área da loja
 * @param nome Nome da loja
 */
public Loja(double area, String nome) {
    setArea(area);
    setNome(nome);
}

/**
 * construtor copia que leva como parametro ums instâncoa de Loja copiando
 * os atributos dessa instância para uma nova instância de Loja(area, nome)
 *
 * @param loja loja que servirá para clonar os atributos para construir uma
 * nova loja.
 */
public Loja(Loja loja) {
    setArea(loja.getArea());
    setNome(loja.getNome());
}

/**
 * Construtor que não recebe parâmetros logo usa o valor por omissão
 */
public Loja() {
    setArea(AREA_POR_OMISSAO);
    setNome(NOME_POR_OMISSAO);
}

/**
 * Método que retorna o valor da área
 *
 * @return area da loja
 */
public double getArea() {
    return area;
}

/**
 * método qeu retorna o nome da loja
 *
 * @return Nome da loja
 */
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

/**
 * Método que retorna o valor da renda fixa da loja
 *
 * @return valor da renda fixa
 */
public double getRendaFixa() {
    return rendaFixa;
}

/**
 * Método que retorna a classificação da loja
 *
 * @return classificação da loja
 */
public Classificacao getClassificacao() {
    if (area < CLASSIFICACAO_INFERIOR) {
        return Classificacao.pequena;
    } else if (area > CLASSIFICACAO_SUPERIOR) {
        return Classificacao.grande;
    }
    return Classificacao.media;

}

/**
 * Método que permite a alteração do valor da área
 *
 * lança uma excessão do tipo IllegalArguemntException caso a area seja
 * invalida ou seja: area menor que a area minima de loja(<5>)
 *
 * @param area Área da loja
 */
public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}

/**
 * Método que permite alteração do nome da loja
 *
 * @param nome Nome da loja
 */
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

/**
 * Método toString que imprime na consola os atributos da loja
 *
 * @return String com valores da loja
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Nome da loja: %s%nArea da loja: %f  Renda Fixa: %f €%n",
            area, rendaFixa, nome);
}

/**
 * Método que calcula a arenda a pagar pela loja
 *
 * Para ser especificado nas subclasses
 *
 * não usado polimorfismo na classe Quiosque porque classe têm o seu próprio
 * valor de renda a pagar
 *
 * @return valor da renda a pagar pela loja
 */
public double calcularRendaAPagar() {
    return rendaFixa * (1 + area / DIVIDENDO_DE_AREA);
}

}
```

`calcularRendaAPagar`is `rentToPay()`

i used this method without abstract modifier to use polymorphism because every subclass has at least this structure. however, when i add another method like

```
  public double allExpenses(){
   return calcularRendaAPagar();
  }
```

or...

```
  public double allExpenses(){
     return 0;
  }
```

noone of the subclasses which are not abstract, "ask"fo

Comment: concrete sub-classes must implement any abstract methods, but they don't have to implement non-abstract methods (since they already have an implementation in the abstract class).

Comment: You should check what is a real abstract method.

Comment: The code in the question has basic syntax and structure issues. You've missed out the word `class` on the first line, and `abstract` methods *can't* have a method body. Please update the question with a [mcve] of your actual code, we can't help you with fragmentary, incomplete, and/or incorrect information.

Comment: *"none of the subclasses ask for this allExpenses()"* Why would they? It's provided by the superclass. (And that statement is the opposite of what your question title says.) Again, please update the question with an MCVE demonstrating the problem without basic syntax errors.

Comment: so how can i force every subclass to have this method?

Comment: To clarify, you want to have a method called `allExpenses()` in every subclass. Does this method have a default implementation which only some subclasses will need to override or do you want to force each subclass to create its own implementation?

Comment: In the latter case, you must declare the method to be abstract (i. e. `public abstract double allExpenses();`) and omit the method implementation in `Loja` (hence the `;` at the end of the line). This will trigger a compilation error if any subclass does not implement this method.

Comment: @vatbub this method has a default implementation which consists of having the `calcularRendaAPagar` plus other costs that which will be specified in each subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superclasses can be abstract or not.

Abstract superclass can define abstract methods (without implementation) and concrete methods (with implementation).

The key point here is that if you use concrete methods from the derived classed - they are not obligated to provide any implementation. The can use implementation from parent class and override it on demand if they need it.

All the abstract methods need to be implemented in derived classes (or defined abstract in case if derived class is also abstract) because you cannot use them without implementation. To force all classes derived classes to implement something you need to declare abstract methods.

```
public abstract class AbstractOne {

    // Obligated to implement in all derived concrete classes
    public abstract void pay();

    // Can be used as is or could be overrided
    public void getTax() {
        System.out.println("Getting general tax");
    }
}

public class Derived1 extends AbstractOne {

    // Obligated to override
    @Override
    public void pay() {
        System.out.println("Pay by cash");
    }
}

public class Derived2 extends AbstractOne {

    // Obligated to override
    @Override
    public void pay() {
        System.out.println("Pay by card");
    }

    // Optional override
    @Override
    public void getTax() {
        System.out.println("Some new tax");
    }
}
```

Comment: yhea, sorry. it was a dumb mistake of mine. haven no idea how i coulnd't figure this out